# Trackbar keeps stealing my focus

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, focus, trackbar

It has been asked a few times but I couldn't use any of the answers.
My problem is that everytime I want to change the trackbars value is keeps focused even when I'm clicking on other parts of the window. And when I want to use the keys they just work in the trackbarbox.

What did I try?:

-I tried to set `CausesValidation`/`TabStop`/`Topmost` to `false`/`true`

-I tried to use the `MouseLeave`/`FocusEnter` events to set the focus back on my form with `this.Focus()`

-I tried to put

```
protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
{
   return true;
}
```

and/or

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
   get { return true; }
}
```

into the Maincode

Here a screenshot of the programm to understand my problem:
[It's german but that doesn't matter. I want to press Enter while I'm drawing the line but the trackbar keeps focused and blocks it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3O23.png)

Comment: Set the focus to something else? You can't focus the form - there is nothing to focus. You can focus an off-screen TextBox as a last resort.

Comment: But I have to react  to my Form Keypress event

Comment: Use a `mouse-down/click' event on the client From area as well (where you also have this keypress-event), in that event handler remove the focus or set to focus to another control.

Comment: @bravobyte so react to the keypresses on the textbox instead. Control all through one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to to override the `OnKeyDown` event after setting `KeyPreview = true`:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        // your code here..
        Text = "Testing: KeyCode" + e.KeyCode;
    }
```

But you can also use the `PreviewKeyDown` event. Make sure to set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to true and also add a common event to all controls that might steal/receive focus!

Since the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the Controls usees a different argument you need to route the event to the Form's `KeyDown` event:

```
    private void CommonPreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1_KeyDown(this, new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyCode));
    }



    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // your code here..
        Text = "Testing: KeyCode" + e.KeyCode;
    }
```

You may want to hook up the handles in code:

```
    void routeKeys(Control container)
    {
       foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
            if (ctl.CanFocus) ctl.PreviewKeyDown += CommonPreviewKeyDown;

    }
```

Call it like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        routeKeys(this);
    }
```

Of course you may want to add **filters** to prevent the routing of keys that your form is not going to process..

**A difference** between the two techniques is the when you override the `Form.OnKeyDown` you will receive keyevents from anywhere; this will include e.g. Textboxes where both your character and your editing keys are routed to the form.

If you don't want that you need to add a filter to the event:

```
if (tb_notes.Focused) return;
if (tb_moreNotes.Focused) return;
if (rtb_edit.Focused) return;
```

The second way let's you decide which controls shall be included or excluded in the routing..:

```
if (ctl.CanFocus && !(ctl is TextBox || ctl is RichTextBox))            
    ctl.PreviewKeyDown += CommonPreviewKeyDown;
```

Comment: Well it was easier then I thought.. I just had to change the KeyPreview.. Thank yooou